# Predicting values and standard deviation with loess

Tags: r, loess

I have scatterplot of data (`x` and `y` values).  I want to calculate the weighted average and standard deviation as a function of X.  For each one of my points I then want to calculate the number of standard deviations away each value is from the predicted.  I am currently using the `loess.sd` function from the `msir` package since it calculates the sd for me.  Does anyone know how I can get the predicted sd for each data point?  Or perhaps there is an alternative or better way to address this calculation?  Thanks in advance.

My current code:

```
#... scatter plot of data
plot(xy,ylim=c(0,50),pch=20)
#loess +- 1 sd
std_loess = loess.sd(xy, nsigma =1,span=0.3)
# ... add weighted average to plot
lines(std_loess$x,std_loess$y,col="firebrick2")
# .... add weighted sd to plot
lines(std_loess$x,std_loess$y,col="firebrick2")
#.... get observed data points
lines(std_loess$x,std_loess$upper,col="dodgerblue2")
# ... get expected value for each data point
obs = xy[,2]
# ... get predicted sd for each data point
expected = predict(std_loess$model,data.frame(xy))  
# ...get predicted sd for each data point

exp_sd = ??????????????????

# ...get predicted sd for each data point
sd_away = (obs - expected) / exp_sd
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly (but untested in absence of data):

```
exp.fit = expected$fit
# ...get predicted sd for each data point
sd_away = (obs - exp.fit) / expected$se
```

The result of predict.loess is not a vector but that a list with multiple components and the predicted values are in the "fit" component.